# Strings Methods Help Java

Tags: java, string, methods

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String userInput = "";      // stores the user input
    String vowels = "";     // used to store the vowels contained in the user input
    String capitalLetters = ""; // used to store the capital letters in the user input

    int menuChoice;         // stores the menu choice value entered by the user
    userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please type some text in the box below.");

    do {
        menuChoice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose one option from the menue below: \n\n"
                + "1.  List all upper case letters \n"
                + "2.  List all vowels \n"
                + "3.  Replace vowels with underscore \n"
                + "4.  Show the string in reverse \n"
                + "5.  Show each letter on a separate line\n"
                + "6.  Exit \n\n"));

        switch (menuChoice) {
            case 1: // Find all the capital letters in the user input
                for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
                    if (Character.isUpperCase(userInput.charAt(i))) {
                        char cap = userInput.charAt(i);
                        capitalLetters += cap + " ";
                    }
                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The capital letters in the input " + userInput
                        + " are as follows: \n\n" + capitalLetters,
                        "Capital Letters", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                break;

            case 2: // Find all the vowels in the user input
                for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
                    if ((Character.toUpperCase(userInput.charAt(i)) == 'A')
                            || (Character.toUpperCase(userInput.charAt(i)) == 'E')
                            || (Character.toUpperCase(userInput.charAt(i)) == 'I')
                            || (Character.toUpperCase(userInput.charAt(i)) == 'O')
                            || (Character.toUpperCase(userInput.charAt(i)) == 'U')) {
                        vowels += userInput.charAt(i) + " ";
                    }
                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The vowels in the input " + userInput
                        + " are as follows: \n\n" + vowels,
                        "Vowels", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                break;

            case 3: // Replace vowels with underscores

                String underscoreVowels = userInput;

                underscoreVowels = underscoreVowels.replace('A', '_');
                underscoreVowels = underscoreVowels.replace('a', '_');
                underscoreVowels = underscoreVowels.replace('E', '_');
                underscoreVowels = underscoreVowels.replace('e', '_');
                underscoreVowels = underscoreVowels.replace('I', '_');
                underscoreVowels = underscoreVowels.replace('i', '_');
                underscoreVowels = underscoreVowels.replace('O', '_');
                underscoreVowels = underscoreVowels.replace('o', '_');
                underscoreVowels = underscoreVowels.replace('U', '_');
                underscoreVowels = underscoreVowels.replace('u', '_');

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The vowels in the input " + userInput
                        + " replaced by underscores looks like this: \n\n" + underscoreVowels,
                        "Vowels", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                break;

            case 4: // Show the message entered in reverse

                String reverseString = "";

                for (int i = userInput.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    reverseString += userInput.charAt(i);
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The input in reverse order is: \n\n" + reverseString,
                        "Reverse Input", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                break;

            case 5: // Show the message entered in reverse

                String multiLineString = "";

                for (int i = 0; i <= userInput.length() - 1; i++) {
                    multiLineString += userInput.charAt(i) + "\n";
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Below is each character entered on a separate line: \n\n" + multiLineString,
                        "Reverse Input", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                break;

            case 6: // Display a thank you message and exit the program
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks for using my program!! \n\n Have a great day.",
                        "Exit Program", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                break;

            default: // Display and error message if they entered a value not found on the menu
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "*** ERROR *** \n\nThe value you entered, is not a menu option. \n\n Plesee try again.",
                        "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                break;
        }// end switch

    }// end do
    while (menuChoice != 6);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Ok I just need some guidance here. but for each one of the case above needs to have its own method and i need to basically Edit the program by moving the functionality in each of the switch-case statements to new methods.  The new methods should handle all of the string manipulation and then pass back the edited string to the main method to complete the output to the user. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I understand 100% what you want to do. I don't understand what the problem is and where your attempt is?

Comment: As a start, I would suggest editing your program by moving the functionality from each of those case statements into their own, new methods. Those methods can handle all of the string manipulation, and they can return the edited string back to the main method. Output to the user can be done in main.

Comment: Ive missed a few days due to illness.. so I'm a little behind can you show me like and example from like case 1 so i can figure out the rest...and @Kon I missed some days prior to this so I have no idead where to start.

Comment: Read the code in case 1 and describe to me what you believe it does, please.

Comment: In Case 1 it will show all the Upper Case Letters in the word(s) you have entered

Comment: @user3348515 That's right. I'll post a brief, glancing answer below in a moment.

Comment: @user3348515 I've posted a reply.

Comment: @user3348515 Check out the [official Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). In particular, read the tutorial on [defining methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html), it is concise, well-written, and may help you along. Those tutorials might be a good resource in helping you catch up.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to set you in the right direction by demonstrating case 1.

As you mentioned in the comments, this case goes over the characters in some String, and puts all the capital characters in a new String seperated by a space character `" "`. For example, `Hello WorlD` returns a String `H W D`.

So let's put all this code in a method. Should be straightforward.

```
private static String caseOneMethod(String input) {
    //Code here
}
```

This is pretty straightforward. This creates a new method which takes a String input and produces a String output, which is what you want. Now you can replace your Case 1 block with:

```
case 1: // Find all the capital letters in the user input
    capitalLetters = caseOneMethod(userInput);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The capital letters in the input " + userInput + 
    " are as follows: \n\n" + capitalLetters, 
    "Capital Letters", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    break;
```

Comment: ok now is the method you have up there inside the do-while loop or outside of that?

Comment: The method declaration must be done at class level. YOu must have some class, obviously, say `class myHomework { .. }` and in that clase you may have several methods including `main()` which you posted above, and now you can add `caseOneMethod()`

Comment: Ok well if i did it the way it was supposed to be done shouldn't it have to have a return statement or no?

Comment: Yes, the method should return a `String` or it won't compile.

Comment: Now i may sound like an idiot but the code inside Case 1 do i need to delete that out of there? Not like the whole case but only certain parts in it?

Comment: @user3348515 Yes, obviously you need to delete the LOGIC code and replace it with a simple method call, as I showed above. Then I left the message dialog code because that doesn't belong in the method, in my opinion. So instead of writing code inside the case 1 statement, you're telling Java "I already wrote this code inside some method. Just go run this method with this input, and give me the method's output, thanks"

Comment: I'm so slow at learning. So what I understood was that i would copy and paste that for-loop in case one and paste it in the new method.. ok well after i did that i put "return input; because thats what you had in the parentheses..so my question is where do i call that at..if i even said that right. would i call it back in Case 1 some where? I'm sorry if im irritating you with my stupidity. Here is a picture of what i put http://gyazo.com/5a7c5ff1f61c3dfbf92c89fef7e4c0f8

Comment: @user3348515 No this is not correct. The variable in the parentheses `input` is being given to the method to work with. The variable that you return should be the one that you manipulate in the method. In your case, you should create a new String `returnString` or something in your method, store capital letters in it, then at the end write `return returnString`.